# Springboot configuration properties Scoping or Arrays

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

at the moment we are using `Xero SDK` in a Spring-boot project. As we need this service a few apps I wanted to turn it into a starter like package (library).

Now I know how to do that and have them registered and generate the metadata.

But my question is how to do that so the user can configure more then one bean.
 I have Xero config properties in my profile. and I have two beans with Qualifiers.

and I just prefix my properties eg.

```
nz.xero.property.name

au.xero.property.name
```

This works fine but I want to create a package and have the properties picked up by `@ConfigurationProperties`.

But if I do that there will only be one set of values. but if a users has more then one account with xero I don't know how to setup the properties.

This is how I manually do it now.

```
au.xero.AppType=PRIVATE
au.xero.UserAgent=****
au.xero.ConsumerKey=****
au.xero.ConsumerSecret=****
au.xero.PrivateKeyCert=****
au.xero.PrivateKeyPassword=****


nz.xero.AppType=PRIVATE
nz.xero.UserAgent=****
nz.xero.ConsumerKey=****
nz.xero.ConsumerSecret=****
nz.xero.PrivateKeyCert=****
nz.xero.PrivateKeyPassword=****
```

What I want is a way create the package then let the user create as many clients as they need so maybe some array like properties. And only use the Xero prefix.

```
xero[1].property
xero[2].property
```

I hope this is clear as to the question I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that looks like the best Method using the new Binder api in SpringBoot 2